# No Android SDK found SDK tools directory missing

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

Basically I just installed for the first time in my life Android Studio android-studio-ide-182.5264788-windows.exe and when I open it I get:

Missing SDK, No Android found SDK found

I also checked this path: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` but I have not found and Android folder there because I was looking for `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

If I press next next finish I get:

```
Nothing to do!
Android SDK is up to date.
SDK tools directory is missing
```

I have also checked all kind of solutions posted on the internet but none of them fixed my problem.

Comment: You're likely missing `path/to/sdk/platform-tools` - did you install it?

Comment: I am not an android developer, I only installed Android Studio. I don't know what else to install. I thought Android Studio is enough. What should I install in order for Android Studio to work ?

Comment: The SDK. You can find the package installer somewhere under settings IIRC - there's a platform tools package (AFAIK with a name that contains "platform tools"). If it isn't installed, install it. Otherwise, it's an issue with something else (try invalidating the caches and restarting). You can also `cat path/to/sdk/platform-tools` to do the check quickly

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer but it's kinda formulated to be understood by an experienced android developer but not for someone new in this domain. For example what do you mean by "the sdk"?  For me SDK means nothing, only in this Android Studio I have SDK Platforms, SDK tools SDK Update Sites, Android SDK, JDK, NDK.. Secondly, what IIRC means ? What means AFAIK ? How to invalidate the cache? Restart pc or studio? I've reinstalled studio again with no luck.

Comment: Sorry about that. IIRC means if I remember correctly.AFAIK means as far as I know. The SDK is the development kit - it's like the JDK, and basically contains necessary tools and the stdlib (standard library, integrated functions, classes, etc).Invalidating the caches is an option. On the top bar, file -> invalidate caches/restart. The SDK platforms (assuming you don't mean the tools) is (likely, it's been a while since I opened the SDK manager) the sources for the dev kit for a given version of Android. But check whether the platform-tools folder exists if you can't find it in the sdk manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out meanwhile but I forgot to update the question. Basically I had those issues because of the corporate proxy which was blocking some resources when installation was in progress.

The solution for me was to configure the proxy inside Android Studio under `System Settings > HTTP Proxy`. I have set it to Manual proxy configuration.

Besides this I also had to configure some security certificate inside the Java Version which was used by Android Studio. I used this code to do that: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4085.html

The last thing was to run this: `sdkmanager --licenses`. I tried first in `cmd` but it was not working, I don't know for what reason but after I tried in Idea it worked.

After all of these, it worked. I had a small issue with the .. but it got fixed after I went in `Setings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run` and disabled `Instant Run`.

Comment: setting proxy fixed my problem, too. My Intellij Idea doesn't have proxy settings, and it works, didn't even think about it... thanks!

Comment: I seems like google dev currently gives error 403 if the request comes from "some" countries. So you have to setup a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Download the zip file: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip
Unzip it to SDK directory, and files like this:
D:\Android_sdk\platforms
D:\Android_sdk\tools
D:\Android_sdk\SDK Manager.exe
D:\Android_sdk\SDK Readme.txt

Restart Adnroid Studio, Configure->SDK Manager
Then you can change the Android SDK Location to your SDK path

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Saved my day. 

Can you suggest the navigation to this file on android website? Because over time the link keeps getting outdated.

Answer (score 0):

network adapter ipv4 settings or proxy.. I checked that, then it solved.

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After installation Click on configuration Go to SDK manager -> SDK tools and
uncheck “Hide Obsolete Packages”

[Refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCbHX.png)
after that check the mentioned package and install it –
C:\Users..\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin is created or not.

After creating project

- Go to Tools
- AVD manager
- Your virtual device -> Create virtual device
- Select Hardware  :- Nexus 5x (Resolution)
- Next
- Check the latest or download latest one (OS)
- Next
- As it is default settings
- Launch Virtual device